# LiteIDE для GO. Индексация пакетов

Tags: golang, ide, импорт, index

Поставил LiteIDE для разработки на GO, всё бы хорошо, да вот он не видит новых пакетов, причем при первом запуске все было нормально и те проекты которые были тогда продолжают индексироваться. Новые проекты просто не отображаются в предложении для импорта, в Goland всё хорошо.
Возможно кто-то подскажет другую альтернативу фришных(желательно опенсорсных) IDE кроме JetBrains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотри в сторону [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/).

Нужно пару-тройку плагинов еще будет поставить.